# Grant database priviledges does not grant table access privileges

Tags: postgresql

After granting access privileges to a user using this command:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_newly_created_db_name TO my_user_name;`

I find that the granted user still does not have access privileges on the tables inside that database. I checked the privileges on tables using this command:

```
SELECT grantee, string_agg(privilege_type, ', ') AS privileges
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_name='a_table'   
GROUP BY grantee;
```

I wonder if this is the default behaviour of the first `grant on database` command. I didn't find much info about this on the [official doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-grant.html)

Do I need to restart the database to enable the new privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases and tables are two different things. Look at the syntax for databases.

```
GRANT { { CREATE | CONNECT | TEMPORARY | TEMP } [, ...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON DATABASE database_name [, ...]
    TO { [ GROUP ] role_name | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

Granting all privileges `on database database_name` includes the privileges to create databases, connect to them, and to create temporary tables. That's all.

Use `grant all` on individual tables, or on `all tables in schema schema_name` to grant select, insert, update, etc.

```
GRANT { { SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE | TRUNCATE | REFERENCES | TRIGGER }
    [, ...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON { [ TABLE ] table_name [, ...]
         | ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
    TO { [ GROUP ] role_name | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

An alternative is to [change the default privileges in one or more schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html).

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
    [ FOR { ROLE | USER } target_role [, ...] ]
    [ IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] ]
    abbreviated_grant_or_revoke

where abbreviated_grant_or_revoke is one of:

GRANT { { SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE | TRUNCATE | REFERENCES | TRIGGER }
    [, ...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON TABLES
    TO { [ GROUP ] role_name | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Another newbie question, does schema = database?

Comment: A SQL schema is not the same thing as a SQL database. See [CREATE SCHEMA](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createschema.html).